# Power BI LCL shows as a negative number

Tags: powerbi

Good morning. I keep having an issue with Power BI Marketplace's SPC Individual Control Charts.

I'd like to share the pseudo-data I'm using:
[image]

Here are my settings (and visual) inputted into Power BI:
[image]

Now all the data here is correct. However, my concern is how the Lower Control Limit (LCL) appears. The LCL as I understand it is [3x the standard deviation subtracted from the mean](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/control-charts/a-guide-to-control-charts/#:%7E:text=Control%20limits%20are%20calculated%20by,the%20average%20for%20the%20LCL) but as I understand it, [the standard deviation can never be negative](https://socratic.org/questions/can-the-standard-deviation-ever-be-negative#:%7E:text=The%20answer%20to%20this%2C%20is,a%20not%20very%20known%20fact.)

So why does it show the LCL as negative and how can we change that? I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: So why would you be surprised that mean-3*stdev<0?

Comment: So the standard deviation should approximate but never reach 0. It's asymptotic. Plus, if you look at the chart, 3x the LCL is higher than 0 but the LCL displays it as a negative number.

Comment: STDEV is just the square root of the mean variance.  When you multiply it by 3 subtract it from the mean, why wouldn't it be less than zero?